# How can I reuse DateTime and DateTimeZone objects in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I made a function to convert datestrings to other timezones, but my function creates new [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) objects every time it's called. This is bad practice so I looked into how I could reuse the objects.
DateTime has a method called [setDate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php), but it requires a year, month and day as arguments instead of a datestring. DateTimeZone has no such method.

Is there a way I can reuse my DateTime and DateTimeZone objects?

Edit: This function will be called anywhere from 4 to hundreds of times in a single POST, depending on how many dates are being returned from the server.

```
/**
 * Converts a datestring to another timezone
 *
 * @arg $ds (String) - The datestring to be converted
 * @arg $tz (String) - The timezone to convert the datestring to
 *
 * @return (String) - The converted datetime
 */
function convertDateTime($ds, $tz) {
  $fooDateTime = new DateTime($ds);
  $fooTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($tz);

  $newDate = $fooDateTime->setTimezone($fooTimeZone);

  return $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Since when create  a new object is a bad practice?

Comment: @AlexBlex This function will be called multiple times inside a loop, so the objects will be recreated every time.

Comment: And this is bad why...?

Comment: @deceze Back in college I was told creating objects is expensive and can bog down the server, so whenever possible I should re-use objects instead of creating new ones. To quote my instructor, "you don't buy a new car every time you need to go to the store".

Comment: That's a very broad statement and mostly unfounded. Yes, creating a new object is probably more expensive than not creating a new object. Is it expensive enough to "bog down the server"?! **Probably not.** You'd have noticed by now if your server got bogged down by this. Try to benchmark this code vs. whatever alternative you can come up with; likely you won't see any *practically* appreciable difference.

Comment: @deceze I'm trying to maintain best code practice, regardless of how big or small the objects I'm creating are. Can you blame me for that?

Comment: I'm not blaming you, I'm just telling you that you're not committing any best practices sin here at all and are overthinking it.

Comment: Regarding best practices, creating new, immutable objects is better than reusing objects. The chance to introduce hidden issues is very low this way and much higher when the objects are reused.

Comment: I suppose some people thought I was only calling my function once and got confused. I edited my post to clarify.

Comment: _“This function will be called anywhere from 4 to hundreds of times in a single POST”_ – so all in all, it’ll keep the server busy for – what? A fraction of a split microsecond? Go look up the term [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Pffff... *snicker*... Four. Hundred. Whole. Times?! Call me when you get into the millions and it gets vaguely interesting. – I'm being facetious here, but really: don't worry about it until you need to worry about it. Does it *seem* slow at the moment? ... Nope, didn't think so. Computers are, if anything, ***fast***. That's what they're good at. 400 times anything is hardly worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to the work that is going on in the `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` constructors, the overhead of initialising a new object is miniscule. What is really happening when you call those functions?

1. The input is being parsed, validated, deconstructed, and in case of `DateTimeZone` timezone information is being loaded from somewhere.
2. That data is being stored somewhere (in object properties, but might as well be in variables, an array or whatever else).
3. You get a handle back to the result of the work which just happened (your new object).

Since every date is unique, this work needs to happen anyway for each date. Whether this is dressed up as an object or as a regular function call which returns an array or something is irrelevant and makes little difference.

Arguably you could memoize the `DateTimeZone` objects, since identical timezones are identical and immutable anyway. Something like:

```
static $timezones = [];
if (!isset($timezones[$tz])) {
    $timezones[$tz] = new DateTimeZone($tz);
}
```

But really, for all you know PHP is already optimising this behind the scenes. It probably won't make any appreciable difference in practice.

What you should certainly not do is mutate objects and set entirely new values on them. If you read the list of things that happen above again, it should make sense why; because you don't know what work exactly PHP did there, and you may create inconsistent objects which screw with your business logic due to stupid mistakes.

Comment: So basically you're saying DateTime and DateTimeZone objects are so small that they don't have to be re-used, and even if they were there would be near no performance difference, even if they were constructed hundreds of times?

Comment: I suppose it was worth taking the hit for if I come out knowing more than I did going in. Thanks for the help, and for the lesson on premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, confirm it **IS** a problem. Benchmark your app with current code, then change `convertDateTime` to return a hardcoded string:

```
function convertDateTime($ds, $tz) {
    return '2016-02-03 15:54:00';
}
```

and measure the difference.

If there is any, you can probably memoize responses, but it will increase memory consumption, which IMHO is more valuable.

One more thing to keep in mind. [One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) said:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

In PHP it is extremely true, as the language itself is far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any bad practice creating multiple `DateObject` instances, but if you prefer a unique instance, you can extend the `DateTime` class:

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    public function convertDateTime( $ds, $tz )
    {
        $fooTimeZone = new DateTimeZone( $tz );
        $newDate = $this->setTimezone( $fooTimeZone );
        return $newDate->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    }
}
```

It remains the problem of `DateTimeZone` class...

Please note that this is only an example to partially answer to your question ( «How can I reuse DateTime» ) **without getting into the arguments**.

It's easy also add more code to reuse `DateTimeZone`, i.e. setting an array and then populating it when new TimeZone is called. (Edit: see example in *deceze* answer)